# PHP/MySQL - Run a function once date matches one of MySQL rows dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a real time based round system. A round starts at some day, for example `November 28, 2017` and finishes at let's say `December 5, 2017`. These dates are stored in MySQL database.

Now i'd like to run a sequence of scripts specific for round finish and start new round automatically. To do this i'll need some sort of automatic handler to compare current date with the one stored in database and start the sequence of PHP scripts.

What would be the best approach to make it work?
I know that `triggered events` in SQL could make it work, but i think they wouldn't allow me to use php scripts, am I right?

Comment: MySQL EVENT's can only make use off SQL statements they can't call PHP code.. You need to go cronjob on this one.

Comment: In which operating system are your scripts running?

Comment: @T30 it's Linux

Comment: @RaymondNijland Just gave it a glance, seems like this is what i'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/udf-compiling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER round_system    
AFTER UPDATE ON rounds
FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN    
  DECLARE result INT;    
  SET result = sys_exec('C:/php/php.exe C:/path/to/check_round.php');     
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This one gave me the `function sys_exec does not exist` alert, seems like i'd need to write some sort of compiler to make it work in my MySQL right?

Comment: Sorry i didn't tell you, sys_exec is not a standard mysql function.  UDF plugin, and must be installed separately: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme